# How do I dynamically customize ElasticSearch Watcher Actions with Expression script?

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, expression, elasticsearch-watcher

My `Input` clause produces a value `A` and another value `B`, and I want to send an email notification with some text that contain the result of `A/B` in it. I had an early version that worked locally where I used a Groovy script in a `Transform` clause so I had a new variable `ctx.payload.result` holding the result of `A/B`, but elastic.co will only let me use Expression scripts because of security reasons. I also tried to resolve the expression inline in the email's body `{{var}}` tag, but apparently it doesn't resolve expressions.

Remember, *I can't use Groovy to modify the payload*. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "elastic.co"?

Comment: I mean the ElasticSearch managed cloud service hosted at elastic.co

Answer (score 0):

Elastic's Cloud allows users to enable the Groovy scripts as well (disabled by default). From the cluster creation page of Cloud:

> Elasticsearch can use scripts to implement flexible ranking, filtering, faceting and more. It is important to restrict their usage, as they enable arbitrary code execution. When enabling sandboxed scripts the Painless scripting language is enabled in 5.0. In the older versions "expression" and "mustache" languages will be enabled. When enabling all scripts, Groovy and any language provided by plugins will be available.

Comment: Thats what I meant by _security reasons_. I can't just enable free scripting in the production environment... =/